# How can I get off the OS X beta track?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I’m on OS X Yosemite — I upgraded earlier, using a developer build.

Now I keep getting pre-release seeds for OS X updates, but I don’t want them. How can I opt out of this and mark my computer as a candidate for only stable releases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On `System Preferences → App Store` you have an option called `Your computer is set to receive pre-releases Software Update seeds`, use the button `Change` and select `Do Not Show Pre-release Updates`.